# pandas count consecutive values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is my data after comparing two dataframes:

```
frames = [9,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,23,24,25,30]
df1 = [75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75]
df2 = [*[0]*len(df1)]
d = {'frames':frames,'a':df1, 'b':df2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I need to count consecutive frames, count starts after two consecutive values:

```
counter = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
df['c'] = counter
result = counter.count(1)
```

I can't figure it out, maybe there is a way to do it with pandas? Thanks!

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: What is the expected value of `result`? You want to count whenever consecutive a pair of values occur? So the 'consecutive count' of `1` would be 3? And `0` would be 4?

Comment: i need the result which is 5. df['c'] is optional, just to illustrate my point.

Comment: @crunker99 the epected value is 5 (you could run the code btw). I need to count whatever consecutive value starting with third consecutive value, 0 here is just reset counter.

Comment: Oh so `counter` is what you want the actual column to be. That wasn't clear. I see now you are talking about values that are 1 greater than previous value.

Comment: @crunker99 yes, sorry if my question is unclear. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff()` to check for a sequence and `shift()` to skip extra matches.

```
df['c'] = ((s := df.frames.diff().eq(1)) & s.shift(1)).astype(int)
print(df)
```

```
    frames   a  b  c
0        9  75  0  0
1       12  75  0  0
2       14  75  0  0
3       15  75  0  0
4       16  75  0  1
5       17  75  0  1
6       18  75  0  1
7       22  75  0  0
8       23  75  0  0
9       24  75  0  1
10      25  75  0  1
11      30  75  0  0
```

Comment: Note that this solution requires python 3.8+ because it uses the walrus operator.

Comment: @Sandertjuhh it can be done without walrus in 1 extra line

Comment: I know, just as a sidenote for OP :). Nice solution!

Comment: @АлексейР thank you, this will do the thing. Also amazing oneliner :))